# Is there a way to turn alcohol into a solid gel?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, alcohols

I'm wondering if there is a way to turn alcohol or another bacteria killing substance into a solid gel form, sort of like the gel you can use to clean a keyboard.

[image: Computer Cleaning Compound Super Clean Slimy]

> Source: Aliexpress.com [Computer Cleaning Compound](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-New-Keyboard-Cyber-Computer-Cleaning-Compound-Super-Clean-Slimy-Magic-Gel/587470728.html)

I'm wondering if you could put either alcohol or other sanitizer into this sort of gel, without the sanitizer having a "best before" date.

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to chemistry so forgive me if there's an obvious reason why this wouldn't work. If it does work, or partially, could you give me a run down on what I would need or need to test to achieve my goal?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎

Comment: I'm not sure how common it is elsewhere, but there is such a thing as alcohol gel which is used as a [hand sanitizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_sanitizer). It's composed chiefly of ethanol and a gelling agent, usually a polymer such as [polyacrylate](https://www.lubrizol.com/PersonalCare/Products/Carbopol/Carbopol940.html). Presumably you could get a more viscous gel simply by stirring in more gelling agent with the ethanol.

Comment: Gelled alcohol is sold under *Sterno* and other brands as a fuel. You can make your own with alcohol and calcium acetate; see http://io9.com/5929133/how-to-make-the-worlds-most-flammable-jelly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your alcohol is ethanol, calcium acetate works very well.  I use calcium acetate to make gel in petri dishes, and sprinkle metal salts on it for colored flame demonstrations.  Calcium acetate is also used in some canned alcohols used for warming/cooking foods.

3 grams of calcium acetate dissolved in 10 ml of water will make a saturated solution (some may not dissolve, which is OK).  This is mixed with 75 ml of 95% ethanol, which will then form a colloidal gel identical to that used in canned alcohol warmers.  I do not know if this gel is suitable for your purposes, but it works well for a heat source.  If used as a heat source, a pinch of salt should be added to the aqueous solution before mixing with alcohol to make the flame more visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try mixing styrofoam with gasoline and alcohol. The gasoline will kind of dissolve the styrofoam and form a paste with imbued alcohol.

Comment: Isn't that basically napalm?... won't be a firm gel though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hydroxypropylcellulose (HPC) as gelling agent.

Comment: This answer could use a bit more detail.